# Algorithm for Weierstrass Preparation Theorem for Formal Power Series

Tags: algorithms, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra, cv.complex-variables, local-rings

The Weierstrass preparation theorem for formal power series rings guarantees that if a given formal series $f(z) = \sum a_k  z^k \in R[[z]]$ where $R$ is a complete local ring with maximal ideal $M$ has $a_k \in M$ for $k < n$ and $a_n \in R^* = M^c$, then

$$
f = (z^n + b_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + b_0)u
$$
where $b_k \in M$ and  $u$ is a unit in $R[[z]]$.

I need an explicit algorithm for calculating this Weierstrass polynomial (or distinguished polynomial) for a given $f$.  In my case the coefficient ring is $R = \mathbb Z_3[[x]]$, formal power series over the 3-adics.  So any algorithm would have to be robust enough to handle these coefficients.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm for a math software package?

Comment: Just a comment, since I don't know and don't have the time to check: maybe you want to look at the documentation of the constructor WEIER in FriCAS whether this is what you want.  If so, the file weier.spad.pamphlet in the FriCAS distribution (http://fricas.sourceforge.net/) contains the source.  Don't hesitate to ask on fricas-devel@googlegroups.com

Comment: I don't think either MAGMA or SAGE have such functionality built in. But it should be trivial to code in any package which handles power series with not-necessarily-field coefficients. Look at Manin's proof in Ch.5 sec.2 of Lang's "Cyclotomic Field", (p.130 of the combined edition), which gives an explicit formula.  

Comment: It seems that Manin's method suggests an algoriithm to approximate the unit power series (that I called "u" above) to any finite degree of precision.  But being interested in the polynomial I would need to calculate u exactly so that I could find f*(u^-1).

The package WEIER seems to only work for field coefficients, though I had trouble executing it.  Entreaties to the FriCAS development group haven't produced a response.

Answer (score 6):

If you're still interested in the answer to this...I also needed an explicit algorithm for calculating associated Weierstrass polynomials and provide two such algorithms in http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4860v2, Algorithms 5.2 and 5.4.  The first one is simplest and is based on Manin's method and a result by Sumida.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an algorithm that I use. Let's call $S$ the degree-$n$ shift operation, sending $\sum c_kz^k$ to $\sum c_{n+k}z^k$, in other words the quotient when you divide a power series by $z^n$. Step 0: divide $f$ by $Sf$, giving you a power series $f_1$ such that $Sf_1\equiv 1$ modulo $M$. Step $i$, for $i > 0$: repeat. At each stage, you get a power series $f_i$ for which $Sf_i\equiv 1 $ modulo $M^i$. For a quicker variant of Step $i$ (for $i > 0$), instead multiply by $2-Sf_i$. It works because you've constructed a convergent infinite product.

Comment: Dear Prof. Lubin, I would also like to thank you for this answer. I am now using this in a small computational project I'm working on. Though, I was wondering, in the "quicker variant", is the rate of convergence faster, or is it just quicker because multiplication is quicker than division?